# To no end VS no end

Tags: idioms

I'm curious to know if my examples are right or the idioms mean the same both ways?

It worries me to no end = It worries me in vain.
it worries me no end = It worries me a lot.

Comment: The fixed nature of the idiom is interfering with the interpretation of your first formulation. The idiom is so common people will either not hear/see the *to* or simply ignore it. Either way the second interpretation is all they'll take away from your phrase. But yes, outside of that practical interference, both interpretations are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound right to just say, "...worries me no end." You need the "to" there. Also, I believe that when people say something worries them "to no end" they are not trying to express that nothing good comes from their worrying, but rather that their worry is never ending.